# Passport authentication not being called

Tags: node.js, express, routes, passport.js

I have code in router

```
router.post('/auth', function(req, res) {
    oauth.auth(req, res);
});
```

correctly hitting

```
accesstokenController.auth = function(req, res) {
  console.log('Here auth called');
    passport.initialize(), passport.authenticate(
      'local', {
        session: false,
        scope: []
      },(req,res)), serialize, generateToken, respond
  };
```

**(req,res) added after getting a link which suggest this**

I belive it should now call

```
passport.use(new Strategy(
  function(username, password, done) {
    console.log('Here pass called with ' + username + ' - ' + password);
    db.authenticate(username, password, done);
  }
));
```

But it never call and timeout occured.

If Id drectly call like this

```
app.post('/auth', passport.initialize(), passport.authenticate('local', { session: false,scope: [] }), serialize, generateToken, respond);
```

this is OK,

In my above method

```
accesstokenController.auth = function(req, res) {
      console.log('Here auth called');
        passport.initialize(), passport.authenticate(
          'local', {
            session: false,
            scope: []
          },(req,res)), serialize, generateToken, respond
      };
```

I have just created a separate method and called it from router page, rather than calling this itslef

What I am missing

Other code

```
const db = {
    updateOrCreate: function(user, cb) {
      cb(null, user);
    },
    authenticate: function(username, password, cb) {
      console.log('Here called');
      User.findOne({ username: username,
        password: password }).exec(function (err, user) {
        if (err) {
          cb(null,null);
        }
        else {
          cb(null,user);
        }
      });
    }
  }

function serialize(req, res, next) {
  console.log('Here pass called with ser ');
  db.updateOrCreate(req.user, function(err, user) {
    if (err) {
      return next(err);
    }
    // we store information needed in token in req.user again
    req.user = {
      id: user.id
    };
    next();
  });
}

function generateToken(req, res, next) {
  req.token = jwt.sign({
    id: req.user.id,
  }, SECRET, {
    expiresIn: TOKENTIME
  });
  next();
}

function respond(req, res) {
  res.status(200).json({
    user: req.user,
    token: req.token
  });
}
```

I have many link related to that but did not manage to solve this

Comment: Is your db.authenticate calling the done function?

Comment: Standard practice is to call `done()` here itself, while returning errors/ data coming from the db call.

Comment: Also, to finally get the response, you need to add `res.send()` in `respond()`

Comment: I have updated the authenticate method

Answer (score 0):

Your strategy needs to return `done()` without which the Strategy doesn't know when it's completed, thus resulting in a timeout.

Difficult to say if this is the exact problem without further context.